# Python: Bad request in POST using requests

Tags: python, http

I am supposed to send this:

`curl --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --request POST --data "ON" example.com/rest/items/z12`

Instead, I am sending this:

```
import requests
headers = {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
url = 'http://example.com/rest/items/z12'
_dict = {"ON": ""}
res = requests.post(url, auth=('demo', 'demo'), params=_dict, headers=headers)
```

And I am getting an Error 400 (Bad Request?)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *POST body* is set to `ON`; use the `data` argument:

```
import requests

headers = {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
url = 'http://example.com/rest/items/z12'

res = requests.post(url, auth=('demo', 'demo'), data="ON", headers=headers)
```

The `params` argument is used for URL query parameters, and by using a dictionary you asked `requests` to encode that to a form encoding; so `?ON=` is added to the URL.

See the [`curl` manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button.

and the [`requests` API](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#main-interface):

> data – (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the `Request`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! I' ve read the manual and in there (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) it does not specifically mention that I have to use "data" in order to add extra data in the POST body. Also by reading `curl` man page it says that --data is used to send request parameters. That is why I chose to use `params`.

Comment: @xpanta: right. I'm not sure where curl states that those are parameters; the first sentence in the documentation that I see does mention it is the POST request. Admittedly this does require some knowledge about how HTTP POST normally works. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`params` parameter in the `requests.post` method is used to add GET parameters to the URL. So you are doing something like this :

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --request POST example.com/rest/items/z12?ON=
```

You should instead use the `data` parameter.

```
import requests
headers = {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
url = 'http://example.com/rest/items/z12'
res = requests.post(url, auth=('demo', 'demo'), data="ON", headers=headers)
```

Moreover, if you give a dictionnary to the data parameter, it will send the payload as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". In your curl command, you send raw string as payload. That's why I changed a bit your example.